# Visual Studio C# Beeps but does not debug

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

For some unknown reason, whenever I try do debug any C# program, C# has started this thing were just just gives the error beep and won't debug. I have to click the stop button and it takes like 15 seconds to stop. Additionally, I can test the program by skipping the debugger via Ctrl+F5.

Comment: Delays that long are usually networking problems.  Try disabling the symbol server.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are trying it in the `Debug` Mode.

[image]

If still not working, Close Visual Studio, ReOpen, Rebuild project and try

Comment: I can't see that Debug drop down. That said I can go "Debug" > "Start Debuggin"